# Exporting Charts as png from excel using python

Tags: python, excel, image, charts

```
def saveExcelGraphAsPNG(comb, InputFolder):
        # Open the excel application using win32com
        o = wincl.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        # Disable alerts and visibility to the user
        o.Visible = False
        o.DisplayAlerts = 0
        # Open workbook
        wb = o.Workbooks.Open(comb)
        # List all the sheet names
        ws=[]
        for sh in wb.Sheets:
            ws.append(sh.Name)


             
        # Create a Directory for storing all the images from the Excel
        try:
            os.stat(InputFolder+'/Image/')
        except:
            os.mkdir(InputFolder+'/Image/')
        for i in range(1,len(ws)): 
            for n, shape in enumerate(o.Sheets(ws[i]).Shapes):
                # Save shape to clipboard, then save what is in the clipboard to the file
                shape.Copy()
                name = 'comb'+str(n)+'.png'
                image = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
                imgFile = InputFolder+'/Image/'+name
                # '_'
                # Saves the image into the existing png file (overwriting) TODO ***** Have try except?
                image.save(imgFile,'png')
                pass
            pass
        pass
        wb.Close(True)
        o.Application.Quit()
        del o
    saveExcelGraphAsPNG(comb, InputFolder)
    print("Images Exported")
```

When I try to execute this python code the following error occurs

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147221040), None)

but when i close the excel app from task manager and run it again the same code works can anyone help me with this